# How to make possible to return structs of different types from one function with Swift?

Tags: json, swift, asynchronous, types, enums

I have this function:

```
 class func cURL (urlT: String, Completion block: @escaping ((Profile) -> ())) {
        
        GetJson.loadJsonFromUrl(fromURLString: urlT) { (result) in
            switch result {
            case .success(let data):
                    
                //Parse
                if let decodedJson = GetJson.ParseJson(jsonData: data) {
                    block(decodedJson)
                }
                
                
            case .failure(let error):
                print("loadJson error:", error)
            }
        }
    }
```

And that's the function ParseJson, probably to modified too:

```
 class func ParseJson(jsonData: Data) -> Profile? {
        do {
            let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(Profile.self, from: jsonData)
            return decodedData
        } catch {
            print("decode error: ",error)
        }
        return nil
    }
```

How can I change the cURL function to return different types of struct, depending on the type of url it receives?

I call cURL this way :

```
cURL(urlT: encodedUrl) { (Json) in print(Json) }
```

For exemple here I give cURL a url1 and it returns a Json of type Profile.
What I try to do is, if I give a url2, I would like it to return a Json of type profile2.

I tried to use an enum with types but I can't get it to work.
Any help would be nice. Thanks.

Comment: You should look into using generics, this is a common use case for generics so it shouldn't be so hard to find suitable tutorials/articles

Answer (score 1):

It took me all night but I found a solution to this using generics:

```
class JSONParser {
    
    typealias result<T> = (Result<T, Error>) -> Void
    
    class func cURL2<T: Decodable>(of type: T.Type,
                             from url: String,
                             Completion block: @escaping ((Any) -> ()) ) {
        
        download(of: T.self, from: url) { (result) in
            switch result {
                
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            case .success(let response):
                block(response)
            }
        }
    }
    
    class func download<T: Decodable>(of type: T.Type,
                                    from urlString: String,
                                    completion: @escaping result<T>) {
        
            guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {return}
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print(error)
                    completion(.failure(error))
                }
                
                if let data = data {
                    do {
                        let decodedData: T = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
                        completion(.success(decodedData))
                    }
                    catch {
                        print("decode error: ",error)
                    }
                }
            }.resume()
        }
}

JSONParser.cURL2(of: Profile.self, from: url1) {(Json) in
    print(Json)
}
```